# LEFT JOIN with DAX

Tags: sql, dax

I am looking for a way to do a LEFT JOIN like in SQL but with DAX. So let say that I have 2 tables A and B. B is a subset of A.
so having

```
Table A:
  rowa  
  rowb 
  rowc
```

and having

```
Tabel B:
rowa
```

I need TableC with:

```
A.rowa; B.rowa
A.rowb; null
A.rowc; null
```

How can I achieve this with DAX?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
DEFINE
  VAR TABLE1=DATATABLE("L1",STRING,{{1},{2}})
  VAR TABLE2=DATATABLE("L1",STRING,{{1},{3}})
EVALUATE
  NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(TABLE1,ADDCOLUMNS(TABLE2,"L2",[L1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.............

```
NATURALINNERJOIN(<leftJoinTable>, <rightJoinTable>)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done the job with NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(<leftJoinTable>, <rightJoinTable>)  but you need to be aware of the name of the column, can't be duplicate over the 2 tables. Another black spot: if they are 2 identity column in each table, not sure about which identity column is taken for the JOIN. NOTE THAT i did not make any relationship between the 2 tables!

Answer (score 0):

please provide more context and explain what is the problem you are trying to solve.

In general, DAX works with `extended table` which means that it works by default with tables already denormalized according to relationships you define in the data model.

Therefore, unless of specific needs or constraints, it is best practice to define this as a relationship in the data model, and not a left join in DAX formula.
Physical relationships in the data model is what makes DAX execution quick and clear.